# Access DOM elements in popup window in Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my Electron app `renderer.js`, I want to create a popup modal, which loads its own `modal.html`. How do I access DOM elements sitting in this `modal.html`? Using the usual `document.getElementById()` is not working. In the code below, `alert(modalButton)` displays `null`, even though at that point, the modal has already been fully loaded.

`renderer.js`

```
const formModal = () => {
  let popupModal = new remote.BrowserWindow({
    parent: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
    modal: true,
    center: true,
    backgroundColor: modalBkgrdColor,
    frame: false,
    show: false
  });
  popupModal.setMenu(null);
  popupModal.loadFile('app/modal.html');
  popupModal.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    popupModal.show();
  });
}

const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  formModal();
  let modalButton = document.getElementById('modal-button')
  alert(modalButton);
})
```

`modal.html`

```
...
<button id="modal-button">Modal</button>
...
```

Comment: Im not familiar with electron but i think your problem is the following `.loadFile('app/modal.html');` will probably load the html asynchronacly. Therefore the button is not there yet when you try to get the `#modal-button`. You probably need to do that in the `ready-to-show` event handler.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Thanks. After searching around, I think it is the nature of inter-process communication in Electron, not synchronization of loading. Closing this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `document.querySelector()` instead?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

or maybe renderer.js is not linked to the html file properly

Comment: Why would `querySelector()` work when `getElementById()` doesn't?